# Passing dynamical information using ejs and html

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

so I am trying to pass some variable ( number) data to a email template. I am trying to use the ejs like this :

`var compiled = ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync(path_to_file, 'utf-8'));`

```
const mailOptions = {
        from: app.get('senderMail'),
        // Atention***********************
        // Let this hardcoded otherwise it will send email to all db
        to: email,
        subject: sujbjet,
        text: 'Hello Word',
        html: compiled({number : number})
    };
```

and in my html code, I am trying to render something like:

```
<span> <=% number %> </span>
```

But I don't get the actual value of " number ". It renders something like : <%= number

Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You opened the `output` tag in the wrong way. Reversed sign of equality and the percent sign:

```
<span> <%= number %> </span>
```

Comment: Cant believe! Thanks